# Bootstrap subtheme - theme_menu_link(array $variables) not reacting

Tags: theming

I'm using the [Bootstrap theme](https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap) and I've successfuly created a bootstrap subtheme that I named **bootstrapdreve**

I've already overidded successfully two templates, but now I'm facing a problem I'm stuck for hours on.

I wanted to overide the **bootstrap_menu_link** theming function located in **bootstrap/theme/menu/**. 
So I copied it into my

```
bootstrapdreve/template.php
```

and renamed it

```
function bootstrapdreve_menu_link(array $variables)
```

Before bringing my adaptations I set a *dsm('test');* on first line:

```
function bootstrapdreve_menu_link(array $variables) {
  dsm('test');
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    // Prevent dropdown functions from being added to management menu so it
    // does not affect the navbar module.
    if (($element['#original_link']['menu_name'] == 'management') && (module_exists('navbar'))) {
      $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
    }
    elseif ((!empty($element['#original_link']['depth'])) && ($element['#original_link']['depth'] == 1)) {
      // Add our own wrapper.
      unset($element['#below']['#theme_wrappers']);
      $sub_menu = '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' . drupal_render($element['#below']) . '</ul>';
      // Generate as standard dropdown.
      $element['#title'] .= ' <span class="caret"></span>';
      $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'dropdown';
      $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;

      // Set dropdown trigger element to # to prevent inadvertant page loading
      // when a submenu link is clicked.
      $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-target'] = '#';
      $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'dropdown-toggle';
      $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
    }
  }
  // On primary navigation menu, class 'active' is not set on active menu item.
  // @see https://drupal.org/node/1896674
  if (($element['#href'] == $_GET['q'] || ($element['#href'] == '<front>' && drupal_is_front_page())) && (empty($element['#localized_options']['language']))) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'active';
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

... and nothing's displayed

I've followed the idea given by this [subtheme preprocess functions inheritance post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109822/subtheme-preprocess-functions-inheritance) by creating this structure:

```
bootstrapdreve/theme/menu/menu-link.func.php
```

and by setting also a *dsm('test');* at first line of code...

Still no message... and thus as I interpret it no execution of this function...

I don't understand why. Could you please help me find why this theming function overiding doesn't work ?

*Rem.:* There's no problem with the dsm(), I've tried to put one at top of bootstrapdreve/template.php and it works fine...

*Rem. 2:* I've offcourse cleared the cache at every modification I made

Comment: If you put dsm() in the parent theme, can you verify it fires?

Comment: I've putted the dsm('test'); in the bootstrap/theme/menu/menu-link.func.php and there it fires well...

Comment: What version (revision) are you using of bootstrap theme, also you may check the changes in theme directory structure in issues #2170829, #2217037.

Comment: I'm using the 7.x-3.0 version. I've tried with an upgrade to the 7.x-3.1-beta2 version and it didn't change anything

Comment: can you confirm theme registry?

`$registry = theme_get_registry();`
`dsm($registry['menu_link']);`

Answer (score 1):

I maintain a [Bootstrap subtheme](https://github.com/balsama/bootstrap_ignitor) that I use for most of my projects and [I override](https://github.com/balsama/bootstrap_ignitor/blob/7.x-1.0/template.php#L53) [`theme_menu_link()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) in my subtheme using the same method with no problem:

```
/**
 * Overrides bootstrap_menu_link().
 *
 * Resets theme_menu_link() to the default that ships with Drupal. Bootstrap
 * attempts to make every menu with children into a dropdown menu. Remove this
 * function if you want drop down links.
 */
function bootstrap_ignitor_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';
  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

You must have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: You're right, the problem seems to be in my implementation of subtheme. I've gitted and activated your subtheme, set a dsm at the top of your bootstrap_ignitor_menu_link function and it displays well...
Thanks for this trail.

Comment: @Adam Balsam, I made a mistake with the bounty, I wanted to assign 50 for you, sorry for that.

Comment: @regilero Ha! Oh well - glad it could point you in the right direction at least.

Answer (score 1):

try using

option 1:     function THEMENAME_menu_link(**&$variables**) {}

option 2:

```
 /**
* theme_menu_link()
*/
function THEMENAME_menu_link(array $variables) {
//add class for li
   $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $variables['element']['#original_link']['mlid'];
//add class for a
   $variables['element']['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $variables['element']['#original_link']['mlid'];
//dvm($variables['element']);
  return theme_menu_link($variables);
}
```

option 3 :

```
function bootstrapdreve_preprocess_menu_link(&$variables) {
        $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $variables['element']['#original_link']['mlid'];
        $menu_title_class = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "-", strtolower(strip_tags($variables['element']['#title'])));
        // Another option $menu_title_class = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "-", strtolower(strip_tags($variables['element']['#original_link']['link_title'])));
        $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $menu_title_class;

        if ($variables['element']['#original_link']['menu_name'] == 'user-menu') {
            $variables['element']['#localized_options']['html']= true;
            $variables['element']['#title'] = '<span>'.$variables['element']['#title'].'</span>';
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Neither of these options worked, but as Adam Balsam mentionned below, there must be something in the implementation of bootstrap subtheme I've done wrong, because with his subtheme, the dsm appears well...

Comment: So you have tried using (&$variables) instead of (array $variables) in your function call?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `function bootstrapdreve_menu_link(array $variables) {` in your template.php and not in a .func.php file.
If you add it in a func.php file then you need to include this file in the template.php file somehow.

Just copy the code inside template.php and it should work.